# Syntax error near on while using SQLITE on conflict clause

Tags: php, sqlite, insert-update

Here is my syntax where I am trying to update data if already exist but here I am not getting Why this error is coming up I am using SQLITE3.

Can anyone help me with my issue or can suggest me better solution if already on stack then I had tried that.

```
INSERT INTO triplets (`user`, `createtime`, `senderip`, `fromaddress`, `toaddress`, `blockextime`, `retrytime`,`recextime`) VALUES ("zulf", "152.228.249.250", "check@250.compilor.com", "test2@zulf.test", "1655878845", "1655879145", "1655893305", "1656138045") ON CONFLICT(`senderip`, `fromaddress`, `toaddress`) DO UPDATE SET deferred = deferred + 1 AND blockextime = CASE WHEN retrytime < 1658907917 THEN (1655879145) ELSE blockextime END AND retrytime = CASE WHEN retrytime < 1658907917 THEN (1655893305) ELSE retrytime END AND recextime = CASE WHEN retrytime < 1658907917 THEN (1656138045) ELSE recextime END WHERE senderip = "152.228.249.250" AND fromaddress = "check@250.compilor.com";
```

The error

```
Error: near "ON": syntax error
```

Comment: Probably you are using a version of SQLite older than 3.24.0 when UPSERT was introduced.

Comment: I just upgrade my SQLITE but then also I face the same issue. My SQLite version 3.7.17.

Comment: 3.7.17 < 3.24.0

Comment: 3.7.17 is almost a decade old by now (released 2013-05-20), why are you using such an old version?

The better option is obviously to use a contemporary version instead of such a historic one

Comment: Actually I am using Linux.

Comment: Upgrade to the current version 3.39.2

Comment: I'm using Linux, too (Ubuntu 22.04) and I get `SQLite version 3.37.2 2022-01-06 13:25:41` when installing the distributions sqlite3 package. What distribution release do you use if that gives you 3.7.17? I'd assume that any distribution not yet having reached its own End-of-Life date has a more recent version than that?

Comment: Looks as if RedHad Enterprise Linux / CentOS 6 came with sqlite3 3.7.x. If that is indeed your platform you have bigger problems than that as both have reached their end of life date quite a while ago.

SQLite was first released in 2000, so using a release from 2013 in 2022 is really nothing you can still expect to get help for. That's a release that is missing almost have of the products total life

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is of Version there might be a chance that you are using the older version.